# WebView как отобразить локальную html с папки assets/one/localsaite.html?

Tags: android, webview

не отображается html c вложенных папок в assets

```
public class LocalWeb extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mButterflyWebView;

    private void init() {
        mButterflyWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_e100);

        init();
        loadHtmlPage();

    }


    private String getHtmlFromAsset() {
        InputStream is;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String htmlString = null;
        try {

            is = getAssets().open("localsaite.html");

            if (is != null) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                htmlString = builder.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return htmlString;
    }


    private void loadHtmlPage() {
        String htmlString = getHtmlFromAsset();
        if (htmlString != null)
            //mButterflyWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/one/localsaite/", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
            mButterflyWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_assets/one/localsaite/", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "No such page" Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте внести в ваш код 2 исправления.

1. Добавьте название папки (one):

```
 
    is = getAssets().open("one/localsaite.html");
```

2. Замените вызов метода `loadDataWithBaseURL()` на вызов метода `loadData()`:

```
 
mButterflyWebView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

или замените первый параметр на null:

```
mButterflyWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Ведь вам не нужно подгружать дополнительные ресурсы, например, картинки. Поэтому папку для этого не указываем. Если будет нужно подгрузить ресурсы, то проследите за тем, чтобы путь был указан правильно.

Comment: В чем отличие loadDataWithBaseURL() от метода loadData() В loadData()  не читаются некоторые спец символы а также есть проблемы  с кодировкой UTF-8 тогда зачем он ?

Comment: @mtb Может быть, англоязычных товарищей он привлекает своей простотой.. А у вас страница отобразилась?

Comment: Да.Спасибо! Работает

Comment: @mtb Тогда, может, отметьте ответ как правильный, нажав зеленую галку рядом с ним.))